# Get minimum of each group based on hour criteria using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a requirement which I posted in SO. However, I have already written code and works fine. I request your review to know whether it is fool proof/elegant and efficient. Please find the details here in SO post [Question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703423/how-to-get-minimum-of-each-group-for-each-day-based-on-hour-criteria)

**my code**

```
df['time_1']= pd.to_datetime(df['time_1'])
s=pd.to_timedelta(24,unit='h')-(df.time_1-df.time_1.dt.normalize())
df['tdiff'] = df.groupby(df.time_1.dt.date).time_1.diff().shift(-1).fillna(s)
df['t_d'] = df['tdiff'].dt.total_seconds()/3600
df['hr'] = df['time_1'].dt.hour
df['date'] = df['time_1'].dt.date
df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time_1']).day

# here I get the freq and cumsum of each val for each day and each hour.Since sort = 'False', timeorder is retained as is

temp_1 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['subject_id','date','hr','val'], sort=False)['t_d'].agg({'cumduration':sum,'freq':'count'}).reset_index())

# here i remove the `hour` component and sum the value duration in same day but different hours (for example `5` was in 12th hour and 13th hour. we sum them)

temp_2 = pd.DataFrame(temp_1.groupby(['subject_id','date','val'], sort=False)['cumduration'].agg({'sum_of_cumduration':sum,'freq':'count'}).reset_index())

# Later, I create a mask for `> 1` hr criteria  

mask = temp_2.groupby(['subject_id','date'])['sum_of_cumduration'].apply(lambda x: x > 1)
output_1 = pd.DataFrame(temp_2[mask].groupby(['subject_id','date'])['val'].min()).reset_index()

# I check for `< 1 ` hr records here 

output_2 = pd.DataFrame(temp_2[~mask].groupby(['subject_id','date'])['val'].min()).reset_index()

# I finally check for `subject_id` and `date` and then append


output = output_1.append(output_2[~output_2['subject_id'].isin(output_1['subject_id'])])

output
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your indendation seems off in the lines following comments. Could you verify that this code works as posted?

Comment: @AlexV - I fixed the alignment.

Comment: I pasted the code from here to jupyter and it works after fixing the alignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## leave the original data intact

Since `df` is the original data, adding columns to it can have a strange side effect in another part of the calculation. Best is not to touch the original data, and do all the calculations etc in separate series or copied DataFrames

## pd.grouper

You can use `pd.Grouper` to group per day and hour

You can group the date per subject and hour with:

```
df.groupby(["subject_id", pd.Grouper(key="time_1", freq="h"), "val"])
```

Then you don't need all those extra columns "hr", "date" and "day" anymore.
There is no reason for the column "t_d" either. since `timedelta`'s can be counted, summed etc as well.

## aggregation function

Apart from that,  you can design a specific function to get the requested minimum from one such group.

If you supply it data grouped per subject and date, dropping rows with the same `val` and checking whether more than 1hr has passed is a lot easier

```
def day_grouper(group):
    """
    Returns the minimum in `val` that lasted more than 1 hour
    """
    # drop consecutive same values.
    # The first value is retained because it becomes NaN and `NaN != 0`
    group = group.loc[group["val"].diff() != 0]
    # drop those that take less than 1hr
    more_than_1h = group["time_1"].diff().shift(-1) > pd.Timedelta("1h")
    # Check whether the last value started before 23:00
    more_than_1h.iloc[-1] = group["time_1"].iloc[-1].time() < datetime.time(23)
    return group.loc[more_than_1h, "val"].min()
```

This can then be called like this:

```
(
    df.groupby(["subject_id", pd.Grouper(key="time_1", freq="d")])
    .apply(day_grouper)
    .rename("val")
    .reset_index()
)
```

The 2 last rows are to get the format you want

## code formatting

Try to follow Pep-8.

£some of your lines are really long, and convention is a space after a comma.

I use [black](https://github.com/psf/black) to format my source code, so I don't have to worry about long lines, spaces, etc any more

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted. Will incorporate your suggestions. Is my logic foolproof?